# Venus flytrap rig

Tags: animation, rigging

I don't know what is the proper way to rig the head of the venus flytrap so i can make it close or open. I also need to join it with the body (named "tallo") but I dont know how.

[image]

Here is the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ymZq63dnAk_KuAjrMsfk76TV08cCOZoT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: That was what I tried to do from the beginning lol i edited the post now and loaded the file into drive (since its size is too big for blend-exchange)

Answer (score 0):

The way you rigged it is right.
What you have to do is first select each opening and go into edit mode. now select any vertex from the back of the opening from where you want to rotate the thing. NOW press Shift+S and select cursor to selected.
Exit edit mode and right click and go to set origin->origin to 3d Cursor.
Now,rotating the thing makes it rotate from the back part.
Parent it to the bone and things will rotate nicely.

Comment: By the way,I request you to not post something this creepy.I might get nightmares man!

Comment: Heyyy thank you. Your answer worked fine to set the movement of the head of the plant, however this way I can´t join the armature of the head with the armature of the body so they move together. The ideal way for me to move this would be to set an ik so I can move all of the plant from the head and at the same time open or close the plant, but thats the part that I´m missing

Comment: Try parenting the armature of head to armature of body.